# Rails turbo_stream not updating value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks, ruby-on-rails-7

I am new to turbostreams.
In a Rails App i have profile and partners model 1:n

profile/show.html.erb

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag :profile_frame do %>
  <%= render @profile %>
<% end %>
<div id="current_partners_size"> 
 <%= current_user.partners.size %> 
</div>


"New Partner", new_partner_path, data: { turbo_frame: 'profile_frame' }
```

PartnerController create

```
def create
 @partner = Partner.new(partner_params)
 @partner.user_id = current_user.id

 if @partner.save
   respond_to do |format|
    format.html {redirect_to profile_url(current_user), 
        notice:t('form.update_success')}
    end
 else
  render :new
 end
 end

<%= turbo_stream.update "current_partners_size", current_user.partners.size %>
```

When I now create a new Partner it does not update the current_user.partners.size value in the ProfileShow!
With
'format.turbo_stream'
added inside the create action, it updates the value, but does not render the show again.

Do I have to add a render statement as a second stream update? I can't find a way to succeed..
Help would be great. Thanks